# Haskell data definition - what does :| mean?

Tags: haskell

I was reading [this](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2020/11/01/names-are-not-type-safety/) excellent blog post, and came across the following line that I'm not sure what it does:

```
data NonEmpty a = a :| [a]
```

What is `:|` doing here? I tried this out in ghci but wasn't actually able to construct anything of this type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compare it to this line:

```
data PrefixNonEmpty a = MkNonEmpty a [a]
```

Just like that line defines the (prefix) `MkNonEmpty` data constructor, your line defines the (infix) `:|` data constructor.

Comment: To elaborate, the "usual" Haskell rule is that all type constructors must start with a capital letter and functions with a lowercase. For symbolic identifiers, that rule is that type constructors must start with a colon and functions with any other symbol.